# How to change the float value in a script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

Hello im trying to figure out how to change this float value within a script to trigger a animation any tips on how to?

[image: Image to help]

Comment: Have you tried looking into the [API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.SetFloat.html) ...?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the method [`Animator.SetFloat`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.SetFloat.html)

Here is an example from the mentioned link

> ```
> Animator m_Animator;
> float m_HorizontalMovement;
>
> void Start()
> {
>     //Get the animator, which you attach to the GameObject you are intending to animate.
>     m_Animator = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
> }
>
> void Update()
> {
>     //Translate the left and right button presses or the horizontal joystick movements to a float
>     m_HorizontalMovement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
>     //Sends the value from the horizontal axis input to the animator. Change the settings in the
>     //Animator to define when the character is walking or running
>     m_Animator.SetFloat("horizontalSpeed", m_HorizontalMovement);
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
void Start()
{
    m_Animator = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
}

void YourFunction()
{
    m_Animator.SetFloat("Speed", YourValueAsAVariable);
}
```